# How can I pass form values to parameters? Error: Parameter unfilled

Tags: python, flask, active-directory, ldap

I'm new to flask scripting and this is also my first question in this community.

About my problem:
What I found in the forums didn't help me directly (may also be due to my scripting knowledge status, that I didn't understand it correctly?).

What I am trying to do is to create different OUs in Active Directory for projects and their associated companies.

Creating projects OUs to the BASE_DN level works without issues.

*BASE_DN = "OU=Assigned,{}".format(current_app.config['BASE_DN_PORTAL'])*

*BASE_DN_PORTAL='OU=Project Computers,OU=Domain Computers,DC=domain,DC=local'*

But when I try to create under OUs on the projects OUs, does not work because I can not pass the parameter **project_ou**.

Here my way:
On the first page (*act_directory_company_new_ou_first.html*) I ask for the existing project OUs in a SelectBox and with submit I pass the selected value to the second page (*act_directory_company_new_ou_second.html*').

But then when I try to create the sub OU I get the message, **TypeError: BackendAD.get_company() missing 1 required positional argument: 'project_ou'**

Do you guys have an idea how to fill the parameter when the page is loaded or when submit is clicked?

Here my codes:

act_directory_company_new_ou_first.html

```
{% block content %}

  <div class="content-wrapper">
       <!-- content-header -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>New Company in Project - Select Project</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Select Project</h3>
                </div>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('portal_blueprint.new_company_second') }}" id="form_first">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Please select first the project where the company will be added.</label>
                            <br>
                            <select name="project_ou" class="select_proj form-control" id="project_ou">
                                <option selected></option>
                                {% for o in data %}
                                    <option value="{{ o.name }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="{{ url_for('portal_blueprint.new_company_second') }}">
                        <button name="new_company_first" id="new_company_first" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Start Company creation</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="card-footer card-right">
                        <a href="{{ url_for('portal_blueprint.show_projects') }}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Back to Projects/Companies List</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </div>

{% endblock content %}

<!-- Specific Page JS goes HERE  -->
{% block javascripts %}

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="/static/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom -->
    <script>
    $("#project_ou").on('change', function() {
      $('#new_company_first').prop('disabled', this.value !== '' ? false : true);
    });
    </script>

{% endblock javascripts %}
```

act_directory_company_new_ou_second.html

```
{% block content %}

  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- content-header -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1>New Company in Project {{ select }}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card card-primary">     
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Company dataset</h3>
                </div>
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {% if msg %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                            <h5><i class="icon fas fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h5>
                            {{ msg | safe }}
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.project_ou(value=select, class="form-control", type="hidden") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="companyname">Companyname (Max. 10 characters)</label>
                            {{ form.companyname(placeholder="Company name", class="form-control") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Description</label>
                            {{ form.description(placeholder="Description", class="form-control") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="street">Street</label>
                            {{ form.street(placeholder="Street", class="form-control") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="location">Location</label>
                            {{ form.location(placeholder="Location", class="form-control") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="postalcode">Postcode</label>
                            {{ form.postalcode(placeholder="Postcode", class="form-control") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="st">State</label>
                            {{ form.st(placeholder="State", class="form-control") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="co">Country</label>
                            {{ form.co(placeholder="Country", class="form-control") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.businesscategory(value="Company OU", class="form-control", type="hidden") }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" name="new_company_second" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

ad.py (AD Backend)

```
   def get_projects_for_company(self):
        SEARCH_FILTER = '(objectClass=organizationalUnit)'
        BASE_DN = "OU=Assigned,{}".format(current_app.config['BASE_DN_PORTAL'])
        self.ldap_conn.search(search_base=BASE_DN,
                              search_filter=SEARCH_FILTER,
                              search_scope=LEVEL,
                              attributes=['ou'])

        buffer = []

        logger.debug(f"user:{current_user.id} | Query: {BASE_DN}, "
                     f"Filter: {SEARCH_FILTER} "
                     f"LDAP Result: {self.ldap_conn.result}")

        for entry in self.ldap_conn.entries:

            if entry.entry_dn != BASE_DN:
                name = entry.entry_dn.split(',')[0].split('=')[1]

                buffer.append(
                    {"name": name}
                )

        return buffer
        

    def get_company(self, name, project_ou):
        # Build DN
        BASE_DN = f"OU={name},OU={project_ou},OU=Assigned,{current_app.config['BASE_DN_PORTAL']}"
        SEARCH_FILTER = f"(&(name={name})(objectClass=organizationalUnit))"

        self.ldap_conn.search(search_base=BASE_DN,
                              search_filter=SEARCH_FILTER,
                              search_scope=LEVEL,
                              attributes=['ou', 'description', 'l', 'postalcode', 'st', 'co', 'street'])

        logger.debug(
            f"user:{current_user.id} | Query: {name}, "
            f"Filter: {SEARCH_FILTER} "
            f"LDAP Result: {self.ldap_conn.result}")

        buffer = {}

        if len(self.ldap_conn.entries) == 1:
            buffer['name'] = name
            buffer['ou'] = self.ldap_conn.entries[0].entry_dn
            buffer['description'] = self.ldap_conn.entries[0].description
            buffer['street'] = self.ldap_conn.entries[0].street
            buffer['location'] = self.ldap_conn.entries[0].l
            buffer['postalcode'] = self.ldap_conn.entries[0].postalcode
            buffer['st'] = self.ldap_conn.entries[0].st
            buffer['co'] = self.ldap_conn.entries[0].co

        return buffer
```

routes.py

```
@blueprint.route('/project_for_company', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@group_required(["Admins", "Betrieb_Users"])
def get_projects_for_company():
    """
    Show list of projects
    """
    a = BackendAD()
    p = a.get_projects_for_company()
    print(p)

    company = {}
    return render_template(
        'portal/act_directory_company_new_ou_first.html',
        segment='new_ou_first.new',
        company=company,
        data=p
    )

    
        
@blueprint.route('/new_company', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@group_required(["Admins", "Betrieb_Users"])
def new_company_second():
    """
    Create new Company
    """
    select = request.form.get('project_ou')
    print(select)  # just to see what select is

    p_form = CompanyFormCreate(request.form)
    if 'new_company_second' in request.form:
        b = BackendAD()
        # Check if company exists
        if len(b.get_company(p_form.companyname.data)) != 0:
            return render_template('portal/act_directory_company_new_ou_second.html',
                                   segment='new_ou_second.new',
                                   form=p_form,
                                   select=select,
                                   msg='Company already exist.')

        # Create new company
        b.create_new_company(p_form.companyname.data,
                             p_form.description.data,
                             p_form.location.data,
                             p_form.street.data,
                             p_form.postalcode.data,
                             p_form.st.data,
                             p_form.co.data,
                             p_form.businesscategory.data
                             )

        return redirect(url_for('portal_blueprint.show_projects'))

    return render_template('portal/act_directory_company_new_ou_second.html',
                           segment='new_ou_second.new',
                           form=p_form,
                           select=select)
```

forms.py

```
class CompanyFormCreate(FlaskForm):
    project_ou = StringField('Project name', id='project_ou', validators=[DataRequired()])
    companyname = StringField('Company name', id='companyname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = StringField('Description', id='description', validators=[])
    street = StringField('Street', id='street', validators=[])
    location = StringField('Location', id='location', validators=[])
    postalcode = StringField('Postcode', id='postalcode', validators=[])
    st = StringField('State', id='st', validators=[])
    co = StringField('Country', id='co', validators=[])
    businesscategory = StringField('businesscategory', id='businesscategory', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In the line `if len(b.get_company(p_form.companyname.data)) != 0:` you are not providing a value for the required argument `project_ou`.

Comment: Thank you, [EAW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10548137/eaw)  for pointing this out. I changed it to `if len(b.get_company(p_form.project_ou.data, p_form.companyname.data)) != 0:` and it works perfectly now.